# Android: Camera2 API crash only on Google Pixel 2 & 2 XL devices

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm using the Camera2 sample code in one of my apps from here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

It has been working fine until recently the app crashes on image capturing but only on Google Pixel 2 and Pixel 2 XL devices.

Crash report shows the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at ....Camera2BasicFragment$ImageSaver.run (Camera2BasicFragment.java:935)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:65)
```

This is line 935 (ImageSaver class):

```
ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
```

I've tried a few things but I'm unable to test as I do not have a Pixel 2 device. Any suggestions?

**Update (05-Nov-2018):**

So the logical explanation is that the image being returned from the ImageReader is somehow null:

```
@Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireLatestImage(), mFile));
        }
```

Some other posts on SO suggest that the ImageReader format may not be supported. This is the format:

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
 ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
```

But I can't imagine why JPEG would be an unsupported format.

Still looking for an answer!

Comment: that sample app has no `Camera2ApiActivity.java` ...what does line `1173` say?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Sorry, I've now updated the line numbers to match the sample code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: It has been a long time since I used Camera2 API. But here is my hypothesis.

If I remember correctly, that callback is used for the preview. Not for the image taken. Majority of devices allow the preview stream of frames to be in JPEG format, but NOT all of the devices.

The format that ALL devices have is de YUV format. I would say that you can try to change the format to YUV.

Answer (score 0):

All phone have triple camera crash with camera2 api, this work for all the phone which have 2 camera on back or single camera

So its advised to change the API to multi camera one rather than restricting that to 2 or 3 cameras